# How do I disable the "Would you like to set up Livepatch now" message at login?

Tags: canonical-livepatch, ltsp, motd

I have some LTSP clients with Ubuntu 20.04.  Whenever login, there is always a prompt "Would you like to set up Livepatch now".  We would not like to set up Livepatch.  Any command to disable such a prompt upon login?

Answer (score 3):

This message is part of the MOTD (Message of the Day), which is fully editable. There are two steps you'll need to follow:

1. Edit the `motd-news` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/default/motd-news
   ```

   Disable the dynamic MOTD news service by changing a `1` to a `0`:

   ```
   ENABLED=0
   ```

   Save the file and exit.
2. Edit the `80-livepatch` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/update-motd.d/80-livepatch
   ```

   Tell it to exit by adding command on a new row immediately after `#!/bin/sh`:

   ```
   exit 0
   ```

   Save the file and exit.
3. Enjoy a shorter MOTD when SSHing into the machine(s)